# Convolution effect changed from Gimp version 2.8.22 to 2.10.18

Tags: filter, convolution, gimp

I recently had the task to apply several convolution filters at university. While playing around with Gimp version 2.10.18, I noticed that the filters from the exercises I applied did not have the supposed outcome.

I found out that convolution behavior changed from Gimp 2.8.22 to 2.10.18 and wanted to ask if someone knew how to get the old behavior back.

Let me explain what should happen and what actually happens in 2.10.18:

My sample picture looks like this (these are the values in all its pixel rows):
[90 90 150 210 210](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uMmv.png)

I now apply the filter 
0 0 0
0 2 0
0 0 0
with divisor 1 and offset 0.

The maths behind it and Gimp 2.8 tell me that the outcome should be composed of
[180 values on the left side, 255 on the right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqYBy.png)

I don't understand what Gimp 2.10 does, but the outcome just has brighter values (90->125, 150->205, 210->255) instead of the expected change.

Is this a bug or am I somehow missing something? Thanks!

Comment: I don’t know for certain but, as for layer and paint tools old blending modes are still available if one wants to use them, then maybe somewhere in the settings there is a way to use “legacy light” for other operations too. *Or* there might be a conversion to/from gamma-compensated values, which would make the desired effect if one first gamma compensates, then does things like convolution, then gamma decompensates.

Answer (score 1):

A big difference between 2.10 (high-bit-depth) and previous versions (8-bit), is that the 2.10 works in "linear light". In 2.8, the 0..255 values pixels are not a linear representation of the color/luminosity but are [gamma-corrected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction) (so that there are more values for dark tones(*)). Most Gimp 2.8 tools work (incorrectly) directly on these gamma-corrected values. In Gimp 2.10, if you are in 8-bit (and in the general case, using gamma-corrected representation, but this is mostly useful in 8-bit), the pixel data is converted to 32-bit FP linear, removing the gamma compensation, then the required transformation is applied, then the data is converted back to 8-bit, with the gamma compensation reinstated.

**June 2021 Edit**: in 2.10, if you put the image in a high-precision mode, and use the values that are the mathematical equivalents to `90/255`, `15O/255` and `210/255`:

[image]

... you get a result that is equivalent to `180/255`:

[image]

Which confirms that in 2.10 convolution operates on "linear light".

So

- If you want the old behavior, use the old Gimp. But you have to keep in mind that the old behavior was incorrect, even if some workflows could take advantage of it.
- If you wanted to see what a spatial convolution matrix can do, then use Gimp 2.10 in "linear light".

(*) Try this: open two images in Gimp, fill one with a checkerboard pattern and one with grey (128,128,128). Step back until the checkerboard becomes a uniform gray. You'll notice that the plain gray image is darker... so (128,128,128) is not the middle of the luminosity range.

Comment: The question appears to ask "how to get the old behavior back" despite the old behavior being incorrect. Is there a way to prevent Convolution in GIMP 2.10 from transforming the image to linear light, doing the convolution in the  and transforming the image back?

Comment: Then I guess I'll have to take the rest of the question, how to install and use two versions of GIMP side by side (one for a filter chain that simulates NTSC decoding and one for everything else), to Super User or Unix & Linux or Ask Ubuntu.